# How can I get "access_token" for API ? : Bigcommerce API

Tags: php, json, bigcommerce

How can I get "access_token" using below code:

I follow below code:
http://ebanshi.cc/questions/2906664/bigcommerce-auth-callback-w-php-api

Still get error : "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in"

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out!

I just removed the line $connection->useUrlencoded();

Comment: Still not working.

Not get any data in response.